# Lost and found Tooltip in ListPlots

Tags: plotting, tooltip

I came upon a strange `Tooltip` behavior in `ListPlot` and `ListLogPlot`. Consider the following code:

```
data={{{1, 0.755384}, {21, 0.73102}, {41, 0.425711}, {61, 0.344925}, {81,0.298442}, {101, 0.152632}, {121, 0.0959704}, {141, 0.0648073}, {161, 0.04575}, {181, 0.0355283}, {201, 0.0350886}, {221, 0.0697085}, {241, 0.125175}, {261, 0.144639}, {281, 0.0730912}, {301, 0.0833903}}, {{1, 0.244886}, {21, 0.268764}, {41, 0.574521}, {61, 0.655075}, {81, 0.701431}, {101, 0.847269}, {121, 0.903783}, {141, 0.935137}, {161, 0.95431}, {181, 0.964333}, {201, 0.964812}, {221, 0.930292}, {241, 0.874787}, {261, 0.855361}, {281, 0.926909}, {301, 0.916631}}};

ListPlot[
 MapIndexed[Tooltip[#1, {"A", "B"}[[First[#2]]]] &, data], 
 Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

and

```
ListLogPlot[
 MapIndexed[Tooltip[#1, {"A", "B"}[[First[#2]]]] &, data], 
 Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Surprisingly, the `Tooltip` is lost in the first plot but appears in the `LogListPlot`. Does anybody know why and how to rediscover the `Tooltip` in the `ListPlot`?

**EDIT 1:**

To elaborate a Little on the weirdness of the Problem. The `Tooltips` work in `ListPlot` for different data sets.

For example the following Shows perfect `Tooltip`s:

```
data2={{{1, 0.999287}, {21, 0.760537}, {41, Missing[]}, {61, Missing[]}, {81, Missing[]}, {101, Missing[]}, {121, Missing[]}, {141, Missing[]}, {161, Missing[]}, {181, Missing[]}, {201, Missing[]}, {221, Missing[]}, {241, Missing[]}, {261, Missing[]}, {281, Missing[]}, {301, Missing[]}}, {{1, 0.000595082}, {21, 0.172139}, {41, 0.32012}, {61,0.229145}, {81, 0.180066}, {101, 0.0638401}, {121, Missing[]}, {141, Missing[]}, {161, Missing[]}, {181, Missing[]}, {201, Missing[]}, {221, Missing[]}, {241, Missing[]}, {261, Missing[]}, {281, 0.0069369}, {301, Missing[]}}, {{1, Missing[]}, {21, Missing[]}, {41, 0.550466}, {61,0.683027}, {81, 0.744493}, {101, 0.863833}, {121, 0.878976}, {141,0.875153}, {161, 0.865458}, {181, 0.858256}, {201, 0.862768}, {221, 0.904684}, {241, 0.949275}, {261, 0.969743}, {281,0.978723}, {301, 0.820449}}, {{1, Missing[]}, {21, Missing[]}, {41, Missing[]}, {61, Missing[]}, {81, Missing[]}, {101, Missing[]}, {121, 0.0768691}, {141, 0.0943452}, {161, 0.111187}, {181, 0.123562}, {201, 0.12506}, {221,0.0852941}, {241, 0.0385046}, {261, 0.0163843}, {281, Missing[]}, {301, Missing[]}}, {{1, Missing[]}, {21, Missing[]}, {41, Missing[]}, {61, Missing[]}, {81, Missing[]}, {101, Missing[]}, {121, Missing[]}, {141, Missing[]}, {161, Missing[]}, {181, Missing[]}, {201, Missing[]}, {221, Missing[]}, {241, Missing[]}, {261, Missing[]}, {281, Missing[]}, {301, Missing[]}}, {{1, Missing[]}, {21, Missing[]}, {41, Missing[]}, {61, Missing[]}, {81,Missing[]}, {101, Missing[]}, {121, Missing[]}, {141, Missing[]}, {161, Missing[]}, {181, Missing[]}, {201, Missing[]}, {221, Missing[]}, {241, Missing[]}, {261, Missing[]}, {281, Missing[]}, {301, 0.128235}}};

ListPlot[
 MapIndexed[Tooltip[#1, {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"}[[First[#2]]]] &, data], 
 Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: try `ListLinePlot` (you can then drop `Joined->True` as well). Works for me, please confirm (9.0.1). Weird nevertheless!

Comment: Yes `ListLinePlot` works (9.0.1). The strange thing is that I have many instances of `ListPlot`s where the `Tooltip` does NOT vanish.

Comment: @MarkusRoellig Do all those have `Joined -> True` as well?

Comment: @rm-rf Yes, it is always the same plot function just with different data. Weird stuff.

Comment: Hmm... that's weird. I thought it might be related to the fact that `ListPlot` plots points and then somehow the tooltips got stripped when converting to a line, but that doesn't seem to be the case. It does seem to work with `PlotMarkers`, so perhaps you could set the plot markers to be a veeery small size?

Comment: Note that this behaviour is no longer present as of v10.1.0.

Answer (score 7):

I tracked this down a few years ago.  Around version 6 or 7 I was writing a function to put a legend on a plot based on the `Tooltip` wrapped around each data set.  It worked on all plots *except* `ListPlot`.  Back then some of the graphing functions were in an external package instead of built-in, so I could open the package and look at the code.

Apparently, for version 6 the plotting functions had to be rewritten to use the OpenGL instead of the old Postscript(ish) graphics.  They also introduced `Annotations` (such as `Tooltip`) in that version.  All the plotting functions got upgraded to OpenGL, but for some reason `ListPlot` was left out when adding `Annotations`.  Instead, a new function `ListLinePlot` was added.  `ListLinePlot` is not simply `ListPlot` with `Joined->True`, but is newer code than `ListPlot`.

I simply try to remember to use `ListLinePlot`, but most of the time it doesn't matter.

Comment: This appears to be fixed in 10.4

Answer (score 2):

Add to your ListPlot the following option:

```
PerformanceGoal -> "Give me the tooltips!"
```

and you'll have them.
Another way is to use the option:

```
Method -> {"If tooltips are lost", "Find them and plot them"}
```

If you're not comfortable with these commands, use more mathematical

`InterpolationOrder -> 1`